# On Response 302 cookie is not persisting in cookie store

Tags: java, spring, google-chrome

Currently i am using spring boot, with third party authentication
after successful login we are setting a cookie , which is visible in Response Header, and redirecting to referrer client

but in cookie store it is not persisting.

```
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements
    AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    ...
    // save a cookie 
    saveCookie("code.one",randomString,saveCookie)
    .....
     getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, redirectUrl);
}

public static void saveCookie(String cookieName, String value, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, value);
    //maxAge is one month: 30*24*60*60 
    cookie.setMaxAge(2592000);
    cookie.setDomain("projectName");
    cookie.setPath("/");
    response.addCookie(cookie);
    }
}
```

i have test in chrome 62.0.3202.94,
can anyone suggest any solution?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What makes you think that its not persisting? R u sure that there is no domain issue here?

Comment: Sounds like a domain issue - are you directing to a different URL? Or same domain / context-path?